# getting value from nested function

Tags: jquery

I just can not get the value of arr. Any suggestion...

```
function my_f() {
    var arr;
    $.post('data.php', function(data) {
        arr = $.makeArray($("tr",data).map(function(){
            return $(this).attr("id");
        }).get());

        return false;
        //alert(arr); ...this work 
    });
    return arr;
}

alert(my_f()); //return undefined
```

Comment: AJAX calls are asynchronous. Read up on it.

Comment: AJAX is *asynchronous*.  You cannot return a value from an AJAX call.  All work needs to be done in the callback.

Comment: The problem is that the value is returned and "alerted" before the post finishes and assigns the interesting value you really want.

Comment: Nobody is putting code examples here because there are so many ways to do it and the best way depends on what you are trying to accomplish. You show an alert. But we don't know why or how that ties in with the actual application. Plus it would be hard for you to explain all that in sufficient detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that $.post is asynchronous, so when you try to return arr, it doesn't have value yet.

Try something like this:

```
function my_f(callback) {
    $.post('data.php', function(data) {
        var arr = $.makeArray($("tr",data).map(function(){
            return $(this).attr("id");
        }).get());
        callback(arr);
        return false;
    });
}

my_f(alert);
```

Comment: thanks man...that's work...alert data, but haw now put data in some var?

Comment: It is already in your variable called "arr". You should do whatever you need to do inside your callback function. Also, if an answer solves your problem, you can accept it. If this is the most useful answer, please accept it, so future visitors of this page will know instantly which answer solves their problem.

Comment: ok...i made it...but i don't know how now joint that data to var 'name' 
that is another part of code
$.post('data.php', 'name=' + //arr data ???//, function(data) {....

Comment: my_f(function(arr) { $.post('data.php', 'name=' + arr, ...); });

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because `post` is an asynchronous call. When you call `my_f()`, it calls `post` and then returns `arr` without waiting for `post` to complete.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX doesn't work this way.  `$.post` makes an asynchronous request to the server which is almost always going to complete **after** the function that called it has returned.

This is how it usually goes down.

1. Enter Function
2. Send Request
3. Exit Function (returns null because the request hasn't completed)
4. Request Completes (now `arr` is set but it's too late)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your approach. Aside from ajax not working the way you're trying to make it work you're not setting `arr` to anything and your alert is running before everything has loaded. If you wrap your alert in `$( //code to run )` you'll get an alert showing that arr is equal to nothing with the code below

```
function my_f() {
  var arr = '';
  $.post('data.php', function(data) {
  arr = $.makeArray ($("tr",data).map(function(){return $(this).attr("id")}).get());
  return false;
  //alert(arr); ...this work 
});
return arr;
}

$(alert(my_f())); //return undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of your function is executed before the answer is received.

The function which you pass to the post function is your *callback* function. A callback function is a function which is executed when you receive the response.

Also, your "callback" function is not a callback function, because it is executed after calling the post function, not when the answer is received.

Also, alerting an array will not give you much information, use console.log() for testing.

Finally, you can use the relevant value (the value of arr) inside the callback function, not the function called "callback".

I hope this helps you.